# Handsontable afterChange, do calculation, setdatacell stuck in loop

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have a handsontable, when a cell is changed I want to recalculate the current row values.

I am doing this by using the afterChange hook, doing the calculations and then setting the new cell value using setDataAtCell.

The issue is I am getting stuck in an infinite loop because the setDataAtCell is triggering the afterChange it is currently using.

I have tried adding a false variable and setting this to true if it has been run to get around this but this refuses to work. Even if it did work then in my scenario of calculating the data it wouldn't work for me because it would mean if the same data was changed a second time then the recalculation wouldn't occur.

Any ideas on how to solve?

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data,
    stretchH: "all",
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    filters: true,
    dropdownMenu: true,
    formulas: true,
    afterChange: function(changes, source) {

        if( arguments[1] != "loadData" ) {

            if( !changes ) {
                return;
            }

            changedRow = parseInt( changes[0][0] );
            changedRow = changedRow + 1;

            console.log( '-------' );

            // r2 is the current row selected upon mouse up

            var currentRow = changedRow;

            // Get the current data needed for row calculations

            var net = parseInt( hot.getDataAtCell( currentRow, 8 ) );
            var netTrade = parseInt( hot.getDataAtCell( currentRow, 9 ) );
            var deliveryCost = parseInt( hot.getDataAtCell( currentRow, 11 ) );
            var fees = parseInt( hot.getDataAtCell( currentRow, 12 ) );
            var totalCost = parseInt( netTrade + deliveryCost + fees );
            var netProfit = parseInt( net - totalCost );
            var percentProfit = parseInt( netProfit / net );

            console.log( 'test' );

            // Set the new total cost cell data

            hot.setDataAtCell( currentRow, 12, totalCost );

            // Set the new net profit cell data

            hot.setDataAtCell( currentRow, 13, netProfit );

            // Set the new % profit cell data

            hot.setDataAtCell( currentRow, 14, percentProfit );


        }

    },

});
```

Comment: Can you please specify what is *arguments[1]* ? Am I right to assume that it's something you use to not trigger unnecessary calculus when loading your page ?